# Biometrics for UK visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk

My sister want to apply for a UK visitor visa for her family in Jamaica but her 4 years old son is in China. Does he need provide biometrics? If yes, is there anyway he can provide it at a visa office in China?

I couldn't find the information on any websites so hoping someone with experience can share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Should children come to the VFS Global visa application centre for applying for a visa?
>
> Every applicant who is submitting a visa application must attend the visa application centre in person. Children below the age of 5 need to attend the visa application centre to provide a digital photograph, but are not required to provide their fingerprints. Children below the age of 18 need to be accompanied by an adult and this cannot be a member of VFS Global staff.

This is from the UKVI in UAE but the same applies for other places as well.

https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/UAE/frequently_asked_questions.html